# How to Deploy a Flutter app on free cloud?

Tags: firebase, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app

I am a new mobile app developer(Flutter). I just finished my first application for a customer. I used Firebase for the backend. I'm wondering if is there any website like Heroku or Github which you can deploy your mobile app so customers can work with it?

Comment: If your Flutter app is a web app, you can use Firebase Hosting. If it's a native mobile app, see Akif's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Play Store and Apple App Store to share your app. Here is more information for the deployment of an [iOS](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios) app and [Android](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) app.